# Connect with MySQL over SSH in Airflow

Tags: mysql, ssl, ssh, airflow

I want to add a connection to the MySQL server in Airflow. When I do the same in dbeaver. I can connect successfully using the below credentials.

```
Main |
  | Server Host: some.url.com
  | Username: auser
  | Password: fakepasswordforsecurity
    | Save password locally: true
SSH |
  | Use SSH Tunnel: true
  | Host/IP: mynew.url.com
  | User Name: userrr
  | Authentication Method: Public Key
  | Private key file chosen: /home/nofoobar/.ssh/somekey.pem
SSL |
  | Use SSL: true
  Advanced |
    | Require SSL: true
    | Verify server certificate: false
```

I choose the private key file in dbeaver interface.

I am trying this is airflow for hours and I am unable to connect. I am using the below configuration.

```
connection_id: some_random_id
connection type: MySQL
Host: some.url.com
Schema: blank field
Login: auser
Password: fakepasswordforsecurity
Port: 3306
Extra:
{
   "key_file": "/home/nofoobar/.ssh/somekey.pem",
   "conn_timeout": "10",
   "compress": "false",
   "private_key":"-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----hakuna matata..."
}
```

I am getting connection timeout. Kindly help on this.